# Php Select * Where Min() Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to select a single row from my db using a query like this: `Select * FROM List WHERE personStat='waiting' AND depId='Admin' AND min(categoryTime);`. 
Where I can use 3 filters: Waiting, Admin, and the minimum categoryTime.

How can I write my Query?

```
ID      |   personStat        | depId   |   CategotyTime
--------------------------------------------------------
2       |   waintig           | Admin   |   10
5       |   waiting           | Admin   |   5       This will be the answer!!!
7       |   atending          | Conse   |   30
10      |   atending          | Eco     |   20
55      |   complete          | Eco     |   10
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html - you can also order by CategotyTime and get the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use

```
Select * FROM List WHERE personStat='waiting' AND depId='Admin' ORDER BY categoryTime ASC LIMIT 1
```

maybe you have tried:

```
    Select * FROM List WHERE personStat='waiting' AND depId='Admin' AND categoryTime=min(categoryTime);
```

but this won't work in case min(categoryTime) is 5, but the lowest categoryTime for your filters is 10 (for example)

Answer (score 0):

AND min(categoryTime)

```
Select * FROM List WHERE personStat='waiting' AND depId='Admin' AND 'CategotyTime' >10;
```

maybe so?

Answer (score 0):

Use **order by** and **limit** :

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE personStat='waiting' AND depId='Admin' ORDER BY CategotyTime ASC LIMIT 1;
```